# Section summaries in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I frequently use org-mode in Emacs to write long articles and thesis chapters and I keep finding myself frustrated that I have no intermediate view between a section outline and the full text. Does anybody know of a good way to include a summary of some sort (like dot points or a paragraph of text) that can easily be shown and hidden?

What I've tried so far is to use drawers for the summaries. For example:

```
#+TITLE: My article
#+DRAWERS: SUMMARY

* Introduction
* Data and hypotheses
* Results
** First attempt
:SUMMARY:
My first attempt didn't work so well.
:END:

The text of the section goes here...
** Second attempt
:SUMMARY:
I still haven't started my second attempt.
:END:
```

I find that this works great in that the summaries are for the most part hidden and I only see them when I want to. The problem is that I still can't get a summary overview this way, where I can see the summaries of each section and hide the full text.

Maybe there is no obvious solution to this in org-mode, in which case I am not averse to writing one but surely someone else has this same need so I thought I would ask if anyone else has found a solution first.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you find a quick and dirty extension of the :SUMMARY: solution in the question.

Edit: I have added a better help and one way to include `org-summary` into the `org-shifttab` action. But, you can alternatively bind some key to `org-summary`.

```lisp
(defun org-summary ()
  "Include :SUMMARY: drawer into heading if present.
You can use this drawer to write a summary.
As a pre-requisite you should include :SUMMARY: in `org-drawers':

\'(add-to-list 'org-drawers \"SUMMARY\")

 1. In your org-document put a line only containing :SUMMARY: on the line following the header.
 2. End the summary by a line starting with :END:.
 3. Leading indentation for :SUMMARY: and :END: is fine.
 4. The last line in the summary block must not be a blank line.
 5. The first non-blank character within summary lines must not be a colon `:'.

Example:

* I am the header
  :SUMMARY:
    And I am the summary.

    Spanning several lines including newlines.
    In this chapter the following topics are discussed:
    1. The world turns fast.
    2. We cannot always read everything we have written once.
    3. We need a summary.
  :END: Now, we will explain everything in full..."
  (interactive)
  (show-all)
  (let ((outline-heading-end-regexp "
\\([[:blank:]]*:SUMMARY:\\(
[[:blank:]]*[^:[:blank:]].*\\)*
[[:blank:]]*:END:\\)?"))
    (hide-body)
    ))

(add-to-list 'org-drawers "SUMMARY")

;; You can insert org-summary into org-cycle:
(defadvice org-shifttab (around summary activate)
  (if (and (boundp 'org-summary-cycle)
       (null org-summary-cycle)
       (eq org-cycle-global-status 'all))
      (progn
    (org-summary)
    (setq-local org-summary-cycle t)
    (message "SUMMARY")
    )
    ad-do-it
    (setq-local org-summary-cycle nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a [mailing list post](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs-orgmode-gnu/2010-12/msg00650.html) that describes a "synopsis view" that sounds like it would do what you want.  It seems pretty simple: just use `SYNOPSIS` drawers, and then use this function to show a "synopsis view":

```
(defun k-synopsis-view ()
  "Show all headings (contents view) and, if any, their synopsis."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (hide-sublevels 1)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\(^[ \t]*:SYNOPSIS:[. \t]*$\\)" nil t)
      (org-flag-drawer nil)
      (re-search-forward "^[ \t]*:END:[ \t]*" nil t)
      (outline-flag-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0) t))
    (org-content)))
```